# Algorithm A is X times faster than algorithm B: confusion about terminology

Tags: algorithm, performance

**NOTE:** This is a question about talking about performance, without code. If this question fits better in a different stackexchange site, feel free to move it.

If an algorithm `A` takes `60s` of execution, and an algorithm `B` over an input of same size and in the same machine takes `5s` of execution, I'm not sure what formula to use in order to say that `A` is `X` times slower than `B`, or that `B` is `Y` times faster than `A`.

For example, `60/5 = 12`. So I can say that `A` is `12` times slower than `B`, and that `B` is `12` times faster than `A`.

But I can also say that `5/60 = 0.083333`, or that `B` takes `8.3333%` of what `A` takes. That means I have earn `100%-8.33333% = 91.6666%` of time, so that `A` is aprox.`9.16` times faster and `B` is `9.16` times slower.

But in finance, if `money_I_have/money_I_had = 2`, it means I have earned `100%` of what I had before. So I have earn `100%`, and not `200%`. That means that to go from a ratio to a percentage in order to speak you have to substract `1` first. So that `60/5 = 12`; or that `B` is `110%` slower, or `11` times slower.

This so many posibilities have always confused me since years. I usually go for the first way, `slower/faster = R`. After further thinking I have realized that, in particular, if `R < 2`, I automatically translate `R` to a percentage and I say that `B` is `100*(R-1)%` faster and `A` is `100*(R-1)%` slower (for example, `1.2` is translated to `20%` faster and/or slower), but if `R >= 2`, then I say that `B` is `R` times faster and that `A` is `R` times slower, but I don't know if what I do is correct or not.

So starting the question from the beginning, if algorithm `A` takes `N` seconds and algorithm `B`, `M >= N` seconds, how many times is `A` slower than `B`, and how should I translate this to a percentage?

Conversely, how many times is `B` faster than `A`, and how should I translate this amount to a percentage?

This question is not about basic math or something, but about the way we talk when comparing speeds, etc. Which formulas relate to which sentences.

Comment: This seems like a marketing question.  Whether you say the turtle is slower or the rabbit is faster depends mostly on whether you're attempting to call attention to the turtle or the rabbit.

Comment: "This question is not about basic math" - but it is. If a=2b then a is 2 times b, or 2 times greater than b, or 200% greater than b. Moreover, a is b more than b, or 100% more than b. Your claim "so that A is aprox. 9.16 times faster" is completely false. How did 91.6% become 9.16? If anything it should be 0.916, and that doesn't really tell you how many times a is faster. It tells you the difference in time between a and b relative to A. Also I think you mixed up A and B in that particular sentence.

Comment: @Nelfeal: Re: "If a=2b then a is 2 times b, or 2 times greater than b, or 200% greater than b": That's not correct. If a=2b then a is only 100% greater than b.

Comment: @ruakh I suppose it's just ambiguous. I was taught "x times greater than" means "x times as great as", not "x+1 times as great as". Apparently people can't agree which is which.

Comment: @Nelfeal: But surely you wouldn't take "a is 50% greater than b" to mean "a is 50% of b"?

Comment: @Nelfeal I'm glad the confusion is not only mine. It's seems there's an inherent ambiguity in the matter.

Comment: @ruakh I would reply "what do you mean by 50% greater?" or "don't you mean 50% less than?".

Comment: @Peregring-lk It's still basic math, with some ambiguous language on top. The math isn't ambiguous.

Comment: @Nelfeal: Wait, really? How about "x has increased by 50%"?

Comment: @Nelfeal The ambiguity arises when you want to translated math to natural language sentences. It's all about language conventions, but I'm not sure which are those regarding relative comparisions.

Comment: @ruakh Now you've changed every word, so of course the meaning is different. "x has increased by 50%" isn't ambiguous, it means x became x+50%*x.

Comment: @Nelfeal: OK, (hopefully) last one: how about "x is greater than y by 50%"? Do you interpret that analogously to "x is 50% greater than y" (i.e., it's meaningless/contradictory), or analogously to "x has increased by 50%" (i.e., it means "x = 1.5y"), or something else?

Comment: @Peregring-lk In the faster/slower case, I think it's obvious that "a is x times faster than b" means "the time taken by a equals the time taken by b divided by x". Same with slower, with multiplied instead.

Comment: @ruakh I'd say "x is greater than y by 50%" is ill-formed, and would ask to specify "50% of what?", but I guess you can infer "50% of y", which would mean x = 1.5y. I think that's less ambiguous than "x is 50% greater than y", because you can say "x is greater than y by 2" (x = y+2) but you can't say "x is 2 greater than y".

Comment: @Nelfeal: Fascinating; thanks! (FWIW, I absolutely *do* say "x is 2 greater than y" to mean "x = y + 2". Dialect differences can be so surprising sometimes.)

Comment: @ruakh Incidently, I just came across [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451080/x-is-2-greater-than-y-instead-of-x-is-greater-than-y-by-2) that shows at least some people have never seen "x is 2 greater than y" but would agree "x is 2 more than y" to mean x = y+2.

Comment: @ruakh Also note that while I consider myself bilingual, English isn't my native tongue. So I can certainly accept differences of opinion in the meaning of some sentences. After all, language is just a tool for communication, and it falls to the communicator to ensure the meanings are clear.

Comment: @Nelfeal: Thanks for that link! Now I want to ask if you'd accept "x is 50% more than y" (which for me is synonymous with "x is 50% greater than y", i.e. "x = 1.5y"), but this conversation could probably go on forever, so I'll stop now. Thanks for humoring me! :-)

Comment: @ruakh Yes I do accept that, in fact it's more or less what I wrote in my first comment. Simply because I infer the "50%" to mean "50% of y" or "0.5y", and so the sentence becomes "x is 0.5y more than y".

Answer (score 3):

As you've observed, the way that people talk about these things is not entirely consistent.

- I hope that everyone can agree that "30% more" means "1.3 times as much/many", and "30% less/fewer" means "0.7 times as much/many".<sup>1</sup>
- But does "30% faster" mean "30% more operations per second", or does it mean "30% less time per operation"? (Without the "30%", this is simple: "more operations per second" and "less time per operation" are equivalent, so "faster" alone isn't really ambiguous. But with "30% faster", the two interpretations are suddenly different.) In my experience, both interpretations are possible, depending on context. (Honestly, the major factor is just, which metric the speaker has handy. If what you have are *throughput* metrics and one is 30% higher, then that one is "30% faster"; if what you have are *latency* metrics and one is 30% higher, then the other one is "30% faster". The speaker may not even fully register that these two things aren't equivalent.)
- Likewise, does "30% slower" mean "30% more time per operation", or does it mean "30% fewer operations per second"? (I think in my experience it's always meant the former, but [Matt Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483526/matt-timmermans) has commented to say that in *his* experience it usually means the latter; and that does make sense by analogy with cars, where I *think* "30% slower" more often means "30% lower distance over the same time" than "30% more time over the same distance". Though that, too, may depend on context; if two cars run a fixed course and one takes 30% longer, I could well imagine someone describing it as "30% slower".)
- But that isn't an issue with "3 times as fast" or "3 times as slow"; only the "3 times as many operations per second" and "3 times as much time per operation" interpretations are possible, because "3 times less/fewer" would be negative.
- A quirk of English is that people often say "3 times faster" or "3 times slower" to mean "3 times as fast" or "3 times as slow", respectively. I don't know why this is — we don't say "twice faster" to mean "twice as fast" — but, it is. This isn't really logical, but I don't think it's liable to be misunderstood.

So if you want to be precise about it:

- "3 times as fast" and "3 times as slow" are fine.
- "3 times faster" and "3 times slower" should probably be rephrased as "3 times as fast" and "3 times as slow"? (But in practice, there's really no ambiguity here — no English speaker will misinterpret "3 times faster" as meaning "4 times as fast" — so I don't think we need to be dogmatic about this.)
- "30% faster" and "30% slower" should probably be completely recast by referring directly to the metric in question: "30% higher throughput", "30% higher latency", etc.
- It's also fine to recast "3 times as fast" and "3 times as slow" by referring directly to the metric in question, and if you want consistency, that's probably your best bet.

Footnote:

1. Actually, even this isn't universally true. There are urinals in Seattle with labels boasting about "saving 88% more water per use than a standard one-gallon urinal", when what they really mean is that they *use* 88% *less* water. In principle, "saving 88% more water" should mean that standard urinals save *x* units of water and these urinals save 1.88*x* units of water; but that's obviously not what this label means. The marketing desire to talk about "saving water" clearly trumped any desire to be mathematically precise. Make of that what you will!

Comment: I think "30% slower" usually means 0.7 times as fast, just like 30% less means 0.7 times as much, not 1/1.3 times as fast. Personally, I avoid that kind of language.  I suppose it depends on whether you're actually measuring speed or time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: Hmm, I see what you mean. If a car is "30% slower", that usually means that its speed in miles-per-hour is 30% less. For some reason that reading doesn't work for me in a computing context -- even if I prime myself to think about throughput/operations-per-second, I still interpret "30% slower" as "takes 1.3 times as long" rather than as "completes 30% fewer operations per second" -- but I can well imagine someone else interpreting it the latter way. :-/